# javascript function to call in order to click OK on confirmation dialog

Tags: selenium

I am writing an automated test in Selenium IDE to test one of our applications.  Our app throws one of those confirmation dialogs "Are you sure you want to continue."
Click OK or Cancel

Selenium does not support the clicking of these dialog boxes.  I have
tried the following SeleniumIDE functions with no success:

```
chooseOkOnNextConfirmation
chooseOkOnNextConfirmationAndWait
```

Is there a JavaScript function I can call within SeleniumIDE to do
this, or am I out of luck.

Answer (score 9):

If you are working on IDE the code should be

```
Command : assertConfirmation
Target : Are you sure you want to continue?
```

This will help you for sure..

If you are working on `WebDriver`, then the code should be

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are going to have to use JavascriptExecutor to press the OK or Cancel button while using Selenium.  You could try something along the lines of -

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.confirm = function(msg){return true;};");
```

That is of course, without seeing any of your code